# how upload file in codeigniter framework

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter. I try to upload file but i didnt get the output. please help me to find out the answer.
my code is

view->upload_form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <title>
        Upload Form
    </title>

<body>
    <?php echo $error; ?>
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload'); ?>


        <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20"/>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

view->upload_success.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <title>
        Upload Form
    </title>

<body>
    <h3>Your file was successfully uploaded!</h3>

    <ul>
        <?php foreach($upload_data as $item => $value); ?>
        <li><?php echo $item; ?>:<?php echo $value; ?></li>

    </ul>
    <p>
        <?php echo anchor('upload','upload another file!'); ?>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

controller->upload

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

When i run the program then it shows the frontend of browse file,but when i select the file and clicked on upload button then it shows blank page.

please help me to find out the answer

Comment: check your log files

Comment: pass field name like if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))

Comment: not working maninderpreet

Comment: read log file in logs folder it contain error

Comment: i am not able to find log file

Comment: in application folder where the controller model view folder exists there are logs folder also open it and read the last log file file name also have today date

Comment: In the log folder there is only index.html file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109138/discussion-between-maninderpreet-singh-and-xr33dx).

Answer (score 0):

check your  './uploads/' permission. You can use chmod to change the permissions.

```
chmod('/path/to/project/folder/images/upload/',0777);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is works fine. I have tested it on my web server. It must be a problem with your permissions to the folder, or the place of your folder. Is your *uploads* folder placed in the directory where you have installed CodeIgniter?

**Place of your folder**

In the CodeIgniter upload library, the 'upload_path' parameter is set to relative to the CodeIgniter folder.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
```

So this means the folder structure needs to be:

```
/system/..
/application/..
/uploads/..
/../..
```

Your *uploads* folder has to be at the same folder as the system or application folder.

**Permissions**

In my webserver, I have created the *uploads* folder with permissions: 755. You can see the permissions of your folder anytime in your FTP program (in FileZilla: right click on the folder > File permissions..). If it's not 755 (or higher), you can also try to set it to this value.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass image field name in following lines.

1. ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');

Please try above point and check.